# Recovering Ubuntu 22 boot partition with GParted or USB stick

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, 22.04, gparted

Recently I have formatted a Windows 10 computer to Ubuntu 22, installing from a USB stick. This computer has two storaged disks (a 2 TB HDD and a 256 GB SSD) and I installed Ubuntu on the SSD, deciding to leave the HDD completely empty.

Earlier today I had been having some sound problems in Ubuntu that I don`t remember previously having in Windows, but just to double check I decided to create a 300 GB partition on the empty HDD and install Windows 10 there to see if the error would happen there as well.

When trying to install Windows 10 from an USB stick I faced an error ("Windows could not prepare the computer to boot into the next phase of installation") on an advanced phase of the installation, halting the installation process. I decided to try again, thinking I had done something wrong earlier in the process, but then I wasn't able to use the same partition I previously tried because it wasn't empty anymore, or something like that (I forgot the exact error the Windows install manager outputted). Then, using the "partition manager" from the Windows installer I emptied that partition and some others that Windows installation created (I emptied/removed only the partitions from the 2 TB HDD, leaving the SSD untouched) and tried to install Windows again. I faced the same error I had faced earlier and decided to forget about installing Windows.

Next, when I turned the computer on again it booted directly to the BIOS manager, and the Ubuntu 22 partition wasn't listed as one of the boot options. I decided to use an Ubuntu USB stick to see if I could get any insight of what might have gone wrong, and with GParted I can see that the SSD is still getting recognized but cannot be mounted. Here's a screenshot of GParted:

[image]

("Label: Recuperação" means something like "Label: Recover")

When I double click on the /dev/sdb1 partition and get more info, this is the output:

```
Warning:
Failed to read last sector (1083390): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't have a valid NTFS.
Maybe you selected the wrong device? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/hda, not /dev/hda1)? Or the other way around?

Failed to open '/dev/sdb1'.

Failed to read last sector (1083390): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't have a valid NTFS.
Maybe you selected the wrong device? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/hda, not /dev/hda1)? Or the other way around?

Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support:  ntfs-3g / ntfsprogs.
```

I tried using GParted "Check" tool to fix this partition, but faced the same error.

My question, then, is how (if possible) I can use GParted to recover this partition, or if it's possible to use the same Ubuntu 22 USB stick I previously when installing to recover it.

---

Edit: Link to BootInfo summary report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BD3NcNSNv2/

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdb1 has 
                       1083391 sectors, but according to the info from fdisk, 
                       it has 1048575 sectors.
    Mounting failed:   Failed to read last sector (1083390): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
Failed to read last sector (1083390): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdc: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdc and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdc: /dev/sdc already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on sdb2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM] from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 2416(5.13) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot enabled according to mokutil - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001
Boot0001* UEFI: KingstonDT 101 G2 PMAP, Partition 2 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(7,0)/HD(2,GPT,f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876d-c8245af921e0,0x95f864,0x2754)..BO


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb2    : isnotESP, fstab-has-bad-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sdb1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sdb

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: 03A3614D-E623-4463-A1DF-B71987932D26
      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sda1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk identifier: 6ABAEFB0-0832-477B-B7E2-5BA4DC728AFC
        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
sdb2  1050624 468860927 467810304 223.1G Linux filesystem
Disk sdc: 14.53 GiB, 15606349824 bytes, 30481152 sectors
Disk identifier: F45E2FA1-C5A6-4D79-876F-C8245AF921E0
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdc1       64  9828451  9828388  4.7G Microsoft basic data
sdc2  9828452  9838519    10068  4.9M EFI System
sdc3  9838520  9839119      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdc4  9842688 30481088 20638401  9.8G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST2000VX008-2E31:;
1:1049kB:2000GB:2000GB:ext4::;
sdb:240GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA ADATA SU630:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:ntfs:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:240GB:240GB:ext4::;
sdc:15.6GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:Kingston DT 101 G2:;
1:32.8kB:5032MB:5032MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:5032MB:5037MB:5155kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:5037MB:5038MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:5039MB:15.6GB:10.6GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
└─sda1 ext4     36b4b1d0-800e-4932-9e84-16491804f34a b7d07aab-beda-4dc2-b71c-2f3aeb5e2151                          
sdb                                                                                                                
├─sdb1 ntfs     D00AC0220AC00784                     85f53d02-d29d-413a-8397-c54b128a3e06 Recuperação              EFI System Partition
└─sdb2 ext4     ef972d4e-1b30-4111-b572-f50a35263ee9 099e66d2-1e4b-42c2-adb5-8ecb24e810d0                          
sdc    iso9660  2023-08-08-01-19-05-00                                                    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64 
├─sdc1 iso9660  2023-08-08-01-19-05-00               f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876e-c8245af921e0 Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdc2 vfat     F7DB-4D56                            f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876d-c8245af921e0 ESP                      Appended2
├─sdc3                                               f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876c-c8245af921e0                          Gap1
└─sdc4 ext4     205ad84b-7713-45f6-b896-559938e0d683 fd2e93c8-7e6b-1b42-abf1-6da693f5d375 writable                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                              Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-11-08.1/crash]  9.1G   0% /var/crash
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-11-08.1/log]    9.1G   0% /var/log
/dev/sda1                                                      1.7T   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sdb2                                                     56.9G  69% /media/ubuntu/ef972d4e-1b30-4111-b572-f50a35263ee9
/dev/sdc1                                                         0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


====================== sdb2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   ef972d4e-1b30-4111-b572-f50a35263ee9
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-36-generic   ef972d4e-1b30-4111-b572-f50a35263ee9
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-26-generic   ef972d4e-1b30-4111-b572-f50a35263ee9
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sdb2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=ef972d4e-1b30-4111-b572-f50a35263ee9 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=2C42-47CD  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sdb2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sdb2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  61.855365753 = 66.416693248   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  61.263824463 = 65.781530624   boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  84.021610260 = 90.217517056   boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic                  1
  61.263824463 = 65.781530624   boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic                  1
  84.021610260 = 90.217517056   boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
  81.831398010 = 87.865794560   boot/initrd.img                                1
  81.416347504 = 87.420137472   boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic               1
  81.831398010 = 87.865794560   boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic               1
  81.416347504 = 87.420137472   boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sdb2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec 18  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec 18  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec 18  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec 18  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 May 17 05:35 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 18  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom

mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1 
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1 


Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
sdb2,
using the following options:  sdb1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS entry (sdb1/efi/****/shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
```

---

Edit2: I tried running the recommended repair but it didn't suceed, saying that "NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr)". Here's the repair pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vWXJZQMdZN.

What seems weird for my ignorant eyes is why EFI System Partition is ntfs, since I don't think it was when I installed Ubuntu. Could it have been "casted" to ntfs for some reason? Or am I just mistaken and it's normal to be ntfs? Please note that I haven't tried to reinstall Windows this time.

---

Edit3: Here's the result of running `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: ADATA SU630     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6ABAEFB0-0832-477B-B7E2-5BA4DC728AFC

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624 468860927 467810304 223.1G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: Is sdb your SSD? Normally installer defaults to ESP on sda? If UEFI install, you would also have to install Windows in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drive. Lets see details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ What brand/model system? What video card/chip?

Comment: Yes, sdb is my SSD. So I had decided to forget about fixing the installation and reinstalling it from scratch again. Then I reinstalled, booted again after installing and no problems. Now I tried to boot again and I'm facing literally the same problem :/ Here's the link to the pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BD3NcNSNv2/

Comment: I tried running the recommended repair but it didn't suceed, saying that "NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr)". Here's the repair pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vWXJZQMdZN/. What seems weird for my ignorant eyes is why EFI System Partition is ntfs, since I don't think it was when I installed Ubuntu. Could it have been "casted" to ntfs for some reason? Or am I just mistaken and it's normal to be ntfs? Please note that I haven't tried to reinstall Windows this time.

Comment: Your EFI partition should not be ntfs, it should be FAT.  Remake it as FAT (gdisk partition type), (mkdosfs?) and reinstall grub.